# error on using GetStatus for usb device Win CE 6.0

Tags: c++, windows, usb, windows-ce

Im trying to get the serial number of a USB device on Windows CE 6.0.

I wanted to use the following function: [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee486973%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx)

```
#include <usbclient.h>

CUSBDeviceInfo::CUSBDeviceInfo(void)
{
    // Get handle for the usb drive
    HANDLE hDrive = CreateFile(_T("DSK1:"), 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hDrive == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;

    // Get USB_FUNCS from device
    WORD wStat;
    USB_FUNCS usbFuncs;
    if (!GetStatus(&usbFuncs, hDrive, NULL, NULL, USB_SEND_TO_DEVICE, 0, &wStat, 2000))
        return;
}
```

With the **USB_FUNCS** struct i can get the serial number of my USB device. The function exists in the header file, but i always get the following error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "GetStatus" in function ""public: __cdecl CUSBDeviceInfo::CUSBDeviceInfo(void)" (??0CUSBDeviceInfo@@QAA@XZ)". USBDeviceInfo.obj
```

I think i need to import a library to my project, but there is no information about a library on MSDN. Does anyone know if i need to import a library (and which library)?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you need to link with usbclient.lib and usbd.lib. If you dont have access to it then you are left with LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress - probably it will be in usbd.dll, but I am not sure if it will always work. I suppose those libs are included with your platform SDK. I am application side developer, I have little to no experience with building platforms.

Comment: These libraries are not included in my SDK and i can't find any information about those libraries.
But thanks for your reply!